# ListBox SelectedItem with List collection

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

All I want to get selected value of "Descr". ListBox loading good, selected, but not getting a value. Got an error: "Unable to cast object of type Customer to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'

```
List<Customers> lstToLoad = new List<Customers>();

public class Customers
{
    public string Descr { get;set; }
    public int AccNum { get; set; }
}

DataSet ds = LoadAvailCustomers();
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
   lstToLoad .Add(new Customers{Descr = dr["Descr"].ToString(),AccNum = (int)dr["AccNum"]});
}

List1.DisplayMember = "Descr";
List1.ValueMember = "AccNum";
List1.DataSource = lstToLoad ;
List1.SelectedIndex = 0;
List1.Select();

string strSelected = ((DataRowView)List1.SelectedItem)["Descr"].ToString(); <<<--error here
```

If I load List1 the old fashion way without collection and class,no problem to get selected item. Appreciate your help guys!

```
string strSelected = List1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string strSelected = ((Customers)List1.SelectedItem).Descr;
```

Be aware that you are adding `Customers` objects to the list instead of `DataRow`s

Comment: If you found my anwswer correct, please mark it as Accepted